# Show errors with alerts with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I want to show errors with alerts using bootstrap, how do I do with vuejs?

This is my code:

```
<div v-if="this.getError">
      <div v-for="(_errors, key) in this.getError">
        <p>{{key.replace('contract_data.','')}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="error in _errors">{{error}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And This is Json :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkBmJ.png

Comment: Welcome in our community, please note that no one knows your project, please include everything what have you tried already, your api calls as well, what errors are you getting, all information will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove "this" keyword in your template. It causes some issues there, specially with v-for loops.

```
<div v-if="getError">
      <div v-for="(_errors, key) in getError">
        <p>{{key.replace('contract_data.','')}}</p>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="error in _errors">{{error}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```